# Why does my LibGdx game black out after a few minutes of playing?

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

Okay, so I've been making a game for the better part of the past month and it's really a fairly simple game. But I'm stuck at an issue where my game will "black out" where the background goes completely black, the fps goes from ~60 straight down to about 0-3 and the game essentially crashes. My only idea that could be causing this is the main "level" class file's render method. Here's the code to Level.java file. If any more info is needed, I'll be happy to provide what I can. Thank you.

http://pastebin.com/AfNceFA8 - Level.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the biggest problem is this:

```
totalDeathText.setText(deathCount);
totalDeathText.setPosition(new Vector2(150, 32)); //<-------

levelDeaths.setText(levelDeathCount);
levelDeaths.setPosition(new Vector2(150, 64)); //<-------

tutText.setText("Press Space to start!");
tutText.setPosition(new Vector2(250, 432)); //<-------
LevelText.setText(levelCount + " fps: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());
LevelText.setPosition(new Vector2(100, 480)); //<-------
```

You are creating new Vectors every frame, that slowly but surely will cause problems. Also do not add the Inpuprocessor every frame, do that in the create/constructos. If that doesn't fix it, then we need more info, like the crash stacktrace

Comment: Thank you very much! I edited the code and will test the solution as soon as I am able to. If it works I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @SketchistGames instead of creating new Vecotr2 you could use myVector = Pools.obtain(Vector2.class) and call Pools.free(myVector) when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: or use the `.setPosition(float x, float y)`